# ffmpeg conditional copy or encode audio stream

Tags: ffmpeg

My objective is to DirectPlay all my content in Plex.
To do this, I have to conditionally re-encode some audio and video streams, to a format that can be played without the server having to transcode on the fly.

I am currently using HanbrakeCLI to encode video to x264 and audio to a compatible format.

I use the "--aencoder copy --audio-fallback ac3" options, to copy the audio stream as is if in a supported format, i.e. aac/ac3/eac3/truehd/dts/dtshd/mp3/flac, or to encode to ac3 if not a supported format.

I want to switch away from HandbrakeCLI because it does not support copying video streams, sometimes my media has a good video stream, but the audio needs to be encoded only, e.g. WMV with a VC1 video and WMAPro audio stream.

A commandline for HandbrakeCLI looks like:

```
    // Create the HandbrakeCLI commandline and execute
    // https://handbrake.fr/docs/en/latest/cli/cli-guide.html
    string commandline = $"--input \"{inputname}\" --output \"{outputname}\" --format av_mkv --encoder x264 " +
                         $"--encoder-preset medium --quality {Settings.Default.VideoEncodeQuality} --subtitle 1,2,3,4 --audio 1,2,3,4 " +
                         $"--aencoder copy --audio-fallback ac3";
```

In ffmpeg I would use:

```
    // Create the FFmpeg commandline and execute
    // https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264
    string commandline = $"-i \"{inputname}\" -c:v libx264 -crf {Settings.Default.VideoEncodeQuality} -preset medium -c:a copy -f matroska \"{outputname}\"";
```

Is there an equivalent to HandbrakeCLI's "--audio-fallback ac3" in ffmpeg?

I.e. I want the video to be encoded to x264, all audio tracks copied if the track is aac or ac3 or eac3 or truehd or dts or dtshd or mp3 or flac, and if not, encoded as ac3, while also copying all the subtitles and chapters as is.

Comment: No such functionality in ffmpeg so you'll have to [script it with help from ffprobe](https://superuser.com/a/1180154/110524).

Comment: Ok, thx, I'll use my own logic.

Comment: did you resolve this? im searching exactly for the same.
currently i use this, but as i understand it convert also existing ac3 twice
```ffmpeg -i "${SRC}" -map 0 -vcodec copy -scodec copy -acodec ac3 "${DST}"```

Comment: @llogan I'm not sure about that, conditional filters seem to be possible: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#toc-Expression-Evaluation